# Can multiple threads write to same row of a csv file but diff columns at same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

I'm a writing a multi-threading python program where each thread will capture some data and write to a column of same row in a csv file **every second**. Say, for example if my csv has column1, column2, column3, column4 as headers(row1):

*1st second:*

T1 will write to row2col1

T2 will write to row2col2

T3 will write to row2col3

T4 will write to row2col4

Again,

*2nd second:*

T1 will write to row3col1

T2 will write to row3col2

T3 will write to row3col3

T4 will write to row3col4

All threads can either write to the file at the same time or through a concurrent queue. Is this possible in python multithreading?

Note: All 4 threads are running in background as daemons.

Comment: *writing a multi-threading python program* - show it

Comment: That seems like a pretty bad idea. Ideally the writing part should be protected by a mutex lock so only one thread may write to the file at a time

Comment: It is possible. You should consider to use barrier or some kind of semaphore that counts the number of threads that finished the row. (It is actually how barrier works)

Comment: Rows in a csv data structure or file are variable length, as are the number of characters in each column — so supporting random access (whether concurrent or not) would be problematic. It would probably be possible to implement what you propose, but it would never be efficient no matter what approach you take.

Comment: It would be better to store the data in memory as a list-of-lists. That way changing the contents of element representing a column would not affect all those in the list following as would be the case if they're stored as comma-separated value in a single string. This data structure would also be each to convert to and from CSV format and therefore easy to write or read from a file, if desired. Coordinating concurrent access could be done using a multiprocessing `Lock` to ensure only one thread modified it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).
Try this code:

```
import queue
import os
import threading

q = queue.Queue()


def producer():
    for i in range(100):
        q.put(f'{threading.current_thread().name}-{i}')


def consumer():
    with open('out.txt', 'w+') as fp:
        while True:
            item = q.get()
            if item is None:
                break
            fp.write(item + os.linesep)


worker = [threading.Thread(target=producer) for _ in range(2)]
[i.start() for i in worker]

master = threading.Thread(target=consumer)
master.start()

[i.join() for i in worker]
q.put(None)
master.join()
```